# Remote logging into site with php

Tags: php, authentication, remote-access, remote-server

I work at chickfila and am trying to make a program that can remotely download files from the companies website. I am currently a CS major senior and have experience with PHP; however, I have little to no experience with curl and situations like this. I am currently attempting to use this program: https://github.com/devall-eu/Login-with-cURL-PHP-on-remote-website, code here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class WS_connect
 *
 * Login and get content of webpage
 */
class WS_connect
{
    protected $username = 'myusername';
    protected $password = 'mypassword';
    var $URL = 'https://login.cfahome.com/login/login.do?prompt=y&bmctx=4D978DCBDE9F3780B15870A0F30E4F91&contextType=external&username=string&password=secure_string&challenge_url=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.cfahome.com%2Flogin%2Flogin.do&request_id=-3375257431464164094&authn_try_count=0&locale=en_US&resource_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.cfahome.com%252F';

    /**
     * WS_connect constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->username;
        $this->password;
        $this->URL;

    }

    /**
     * Connect to web service
     * CURL method
     * @return object
     */
    private function connect()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ":" . $this->password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 400);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        /*
        Set the cookie storing files
        Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
        */

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

        $res = (object)array(
            'response' => curl_exec($ch),
            'info' => (object)curl_getinfo($ch),
            'errors' => curl_error($ch)
        );

        curl_close($ch);

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    private function getData()
    {
        $data = $this->connect();

        if ($data->errors) return $data->errors;
        elseif ($data->response == '') return 'Response is empty!';
        else return $data->response;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|mixed|string
     */
    public function data()
    {
        $response = $this->getData();

        if (!is_array($response)) {
            echo $response;
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            // We finally have data from WS
            return $response;
        }
    }
}

$connector = new WS_connect;
$connector->data();
```

Obviously I've changed the username and password. The program only outputs the login page and to frank, I really have no idea how to troubleshoot or where to go from here. Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: uhum sure.. the site doesn't use auth basic, its a normal form post. Target the files not the login, you could place some code on the website which provides a list of all the files in json etc like a sitemap (protected by a key). You then simply loop over it and download. Else you're going to need to implement a whole lot more like dom parsing and picking up tokens etc

Comment: The code you are referencing is for a username/password in the context of [HTTP basic authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), however the site is using that, so that code itself won't really help you

Comment: sidenote, the login is handled by okta.com sso, you may if entitled to be able to use a php client https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-php

Comment: Thank you all so much! I apologize that the question was so vague, again I really have very little knowledge of this topic at all. Again, thank you for your suggestions!